# jCarousel bug in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, jcarousel

We are trying to get jCarousel work in IE (ver 11) but cant find out how...

When you go to http://cis.gefco-czech.cz/ you can see the first image (or other images) are cut in the middle and right side is white. When this image is shown again, after all slides were shown, this image is magically showing as it is supposed to be.

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this bug?

It works perfect in chrome and safari...

Comment: Hi, you have markup errors... (validator.w3.org/nu )

Answer (score 0):

you have markup errors... (validator.w3.org/nu )
first set up ie to record scripting and markup errors.
Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages".... save changes.... Now you can open your dev tool in IE and the Console tab will list otherwise suppressed error messages.
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
cis.gefco-czech.cz
HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.

Put a space between the id and class attribute. eg. sb id="123" class="someclass" not
id="123"class="someclass"